# How to fix non-working apt upgrade

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg

I have a problem upgrading my Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS Server.

When I run:

`sudo apt upgrade`

I get:

`...`

`Setting up base-files (9.4ubuntu4.11) ...`

And then apt just pauses there and never gets any further.

From the dpkg log I see:

`2020-07-05 17:37:07 configure base-files:amd64 9.4ubuntu4.11 <none>`

`2020-07-05 17:37:07 status half-configured base-files:amd64 9.4ubuntu4.11`

I have tried dpkg --configure -a, but that just produces the same problem.

Does anyone have any idea how I can solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: One quick thought comes to mind.  How much free space to you have in the root partition.  It will need to download lots of files to get ready.

Comment: It's just a little server with 10GB and 3.8GB free. Should be enough I think.

Comment: OK should be enough.  Here is a link to a helpful tutorial.  Maybe some other update is stuck.  Work through the list.  For you this will upgrade first to 18.04 and then if you want to 20.04.  There is no path from 16.04 to 20.04.  https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/upgrade-ubuntu-18-04-to-20-04-lts-using-command-line/